# Planar graph and Finding Triangles

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, discrete-mathematics

Suppose `G` be a planar graph with `16` vertex, that degree of each vertex is `4`.

When we place this graph on plane as a planar graph, each finite region be a trilateral or foursquare and boundary of infinite region is made up by `4` edges.

How many trilateral edge be in such graph? my TA solve and find the triangle is `8` by drawing a figure. Any other idea to calculate it ?

Comment: do you need to calculate it in a program? or just want to do that on paper?

Comment: @Mysterion, i need on a paper, or maybe a clever programming tips :), infact i want to solve it without drawing the graph...

Comment: Doesn't seem programming related to me, this sounds like a math question; you did post it on [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139050/planar-graph-and-trilateral), too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best solved by direct reasoning without a computer involved at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let V be the number of vertices, E be the number of edges, F3 be the number of triangles, and F4 be the number of quads. We have equations

```
V = 16               # given
4 V = 2 E            # number of vertex-edge incidences
3 F3 + 4 F4 = 2 E    # number of face-edge incidences
V - E + F3 + F4 = 2  # Euler's polyhedron formula,
```

which suffice to derive that V = 16, E = 32, F3 = 8, F4 = 10.